# How to automatic send daily message on specific time using thread or cronjob in struts eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Please help me solve this query, I am going to apply send automatic message daily on specific time in eclipse but i am confused so give me suggestion

Comment: use a scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Use Quartz 2.1.5 API

```
<!--Maven Dependency-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5</version>
</dependency>'
```

To integrate Struts 2 and Quartz 2 scheduler we have to use a standard Servlet Listener To Link Quartz API to Struts.
Use ServletContextListener interface like below.

```
QuartzListener.java

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

/**
 * This class is used for executing quartz job 
 * using CronTrigger(Quartz 2.1.5).
 * @author Prabhakar Kumar
 */
public class QuartzListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Destroyed is called.");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        try{
            //Set job details.
            JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
                .withIdentity("helloJob", "group1").build();

            //Set the scheduler timings.
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("cronTrigger", "group1")
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder
                  .cronSchedule("0/10 * * * * ?")).build();
                  //"0/10 * * * * ?"--->here you can put date time day of 
                 //week month just read more about Quartz API
                //Execute the job.
            Scheduler scheduler = 
                new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }
}
```

Your Scheduler Method Look Like

```
 HelloJob.java

    import org.quartz.Job;
    import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
    import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

    /**
     * This class defines a quartz job.
     * @author Prabhakar Kumar
     */
    public class HelloJob implements Job{
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
                throws JobExecutionException {
           //Here is your code in this method(Your Logic)
            System.out.println("Hello World.");      
        }
    }
```

Web.xml will Look Like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >   <web-app> <filter> <filter-name>struts2</filter-name> <filter-class> org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng. filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter </filter-class> </filter>   <filter-mapping> <filter-name>struts2</filter-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping>   <listener> <listener-class> com.javawithease.business.QuartzListener </listener-class> </listener>   </web-app>
```